# to_char() problem decimal points and thousand separator

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I'm trying to convert a number to a string and apply a format using `to_Char` in an Oracle database.

This is what I'm after (example of the value on the left and what I after on the left):

```
0                   --> 0
0.29                --> 0.29
25319,76            --> 25,319.76
12252,136456        --> 12,252.13
```

Best format I can come up with is this in SQL:

```
to_char(var, 'B99,999,999,999.09')
```

This is the result:

```
0                   --> nothing
0.29                --> .29
25319,76            --> 25,319.76
12252,136456        --> 12,252.13
```

So my issue is the 0.29 and 0. How can I get that part to work?

BR Kresten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `B` [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-48089B4F-C697-411C-8254-53A7AC5BDA85):

> Returns blanks for the integer part of a fixed-point number when the integer part is zero (regardless of zeros in the format model).

And since you don't want a blank integer part then you probably don't want to use the `B` format model; instead, you want the `FM` [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA) that:

> Returns a value with no leading or trailing blanks.

You can use `RTRIM( TO_CHAR(var, 'FM99,999,999,990.99' ), '.' )`.

For example:

```sql
SELECT var,
       RTRIM( TO_CHAR(var, 'FM99,999,999,990.99' ), '.' ) AS formatted_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( var ) AS
SELECT     0        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT     0.29     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25319.76     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12252.136456 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>          VAR | FORMATTED_VALUE
> -----------: | :--------------
>            0 | 0              
>          .29 | 0.29           
>     25319.76 | 25,319.76      
> 12252.136456 | 12,252.14
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ff40324597d7dee3f09f787b49a4363)*

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `0` in the format *before* the decimal point.

Also you can add `FM` prefix instead of `B` to get rid of leading spaces and trailing zeroes.

After that you can use `rtrim(..., '.')` to remove the trailing decimal point.

(see [Oracle Format Models documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210))

```
select v, rtrim(to_char(v, 'FM99,999,999,990.99'), '.') from
  (select 0 as v from dual
   union all select 0.29 from dual
   union all select 25319.76 from dual
   union all select 12252.136456 from dual
  ) t
;  

/* output:
           0    0
         .29    0.29
    25319.76    25,319.76
12252.136456    12,252.14
*/
```